# how to compare text/title which have space/special characters in selenium

Tags: selenium

```
Current tag like this <title>share a link on Twitter</title>
```

share a link on Twitter

Getting a title by using driver.gettitle() and copmare by using
Assert.assertequals(driver.gettitle().TextProp.getProperty("twitterloginpagetitle"))

but value not matching.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool windowTitle = driver.Title.equals("twitterloginpagetitle") ? true : false;
```

Comment: it is returning false value, but how to handle space in between text.

Comment: what you mean by saying handle space ? bool windowTitle = driver.Title.equals("share a link on Twitter") ? true : false;

Comment: that code is c# example you can do the same idea, i suppose you using java so it's matter of syntax ..

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:

```
    Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(),"Stack Overflow");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the space in the page title and then compare it with text property value.

```
String title = driver.getTitle().replace(" ","");
Assert.assertEquals(title,TextProp.getProperty("twitterloginpagetitle"));
```